# Can't run application after deleting temporary asp net files

Tags: asp.net

I tried deleting my temporary internet files to fix a breakpoint could not be hit error and now my application won't run. I've tried restarting visual studio and stopping the app in iis express, but nothing seem to work. When it runs it just comes up and says page cannot be displayed and does not tell me why. I tried switching back to cassini from IIS expess, but that didn't help.

```
All I get is this:
This page can't be displayed
Make sure the web address http://localhost:32828 is correct.
```

I've figured out by commenting out different sections of my web config that the problem starts here although I have no idea why deleting my temporary internet files would have any effect on this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" domain="localhost" loginUrl="http://localhost:32825/login/default.aspx" protection="All" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40"/>
</authentication>
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this or at least debug it? I've never had any problems deleting the temporary internet files before.

Comment: Did you delete the Temporary Asp.Net folder or its contents? Deleting the folder will cause wonky behavior. Deleting its contents should free your debug breaks.

Comment: I only deleted the contents.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right then, here is yours:

Web.Config:

```
loginUrl="http://localhost:32825/login/default.aspx"
```

Error:

```
This page can't be displayed. 
Make sure the web address http://localhost:32828 is correct..
```

You can see the two different port numbers. If you have fixed the port number in config file then you have to fix the same in the projects settings too, so as development server will execute on same port every time.

Try this you won't get the error.

Comment: Thanks although the port number is different because its the port number of the website. The web app authenticates from the website which is on the 32825 port.

Comment: This actually helped me track down the problem. I've added an answer to my own question.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites : Accepting as answer will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks, although what you proposed wasn't the solution as you can see in my first comment. I wouldn't want to confuse people with it. I did upvote it though :), so thank you. It made me think to try hitting the url manually once the web app was loaded, so it did point me in the right direction. I listed out all the steps I took to fix it in my other post.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seemed to be two fold. First I had to delete the references in the IIS express configuration file. I then switched both my website and my web app back to use cassini instead of iis express. Secondly I realized that the website asp net development server process had to be running for it to connect from the web app. I'm a little puzzled by this part as it always seemed to fire up automatically, but I'm going to diagnose that separately as it's working for now.